# Non separable differencial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found this equation when trying forecasting gas well production
dy/dx=1+y/(b-cx)
Could you help me solving it?
Thanks

Comment: That's a first order linear differential equation. The standard technique for solving such equations is the integrating factor method.

Answer (score 1):

The equation being $$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac y{b-cx}$$ start letting $$b-cx=t\implies x=\frac{b-t}{c}$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\times \frac{dt}{dx}=-c\,\frac{dy}{dt}$$ which makes $$-c\,\frac{dy}{dt}=1+\frac y{t}\implies c\,\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac y{t}=-1$$ The solution of the homogeneous equation (which is separable) is quite simple$$y=k\, t^{-1/c}$$ Now, variation of the parameters $$y=k\, t^{-1/c}\implies\frac{dy}{dt}=t^{-1/c} k'-\frac{t^{-\frac{1}{c}-1} }{c}k$$ $$c\,\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac y{t}=c t^{-1/c} k'=-1\implies k'=-\frac{t^{\frac{1}{c}}}{c}\implies k=-\frac{t^{\frac{1}{c}+1}}{\left(\frac{1}{c}+1\right) c}+K$$ Back to $y$ $$y=K t^{-1/c}-\frac{t}{\left(\frac{1}{c}+1\right) c}$$ Back to $c$ $$y=K (b-c x)^{-1/c}+\frac{c x-b}{c+1}$$ and $K$ will be fixed by any initial condition.